Understanding what diagrams and morphisms are in the context of slice categories.
This question pertains to Example 3.5 of Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0", and is similar to the question asked here: Example 3.5 in Allufi: Chapter 0 (Slice categories). Let $\mathsf{C}$ be some category and $A \in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathsf{C})$. Aluffi defines a new category $\mathsf{C}_A$ where the objects are "all morphisms from any object of $\mathsf C$ to $A$, so (as  I understand it), the set
$$
\operatorname{Obj}(\mathsf{C}_A) = \left\{ (Z, f) : Z \in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathsf{C}), f \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}_A} (Z,A) \right\}.
$$
(Edited from $\bigcup_{Z \in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathsf{C})} \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(Z, A)$ thanks to a comment). 
Aluffi then defines morphisms between $f_1, f_2 \in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathsf{C}_A)$ with $f_1 : Z_1 \to A$ and $f_2 : Z_2 \to A$ with $Z_1, Z_2\in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathsf C)$ as the following commutative diagram:

He states that this corresponds precisely to those $\sigma \in \mathrm{Hom}(Z_1, Z_2)$ such that $f_1 = f_2 \circ \sigma$, i.e., such that the diagram commutes.
Now, I am not entirely clear on what the set $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}_A}(f_1, f_2)$ is exactly. Is it the diagram, so a set of objects with a set of morphisms, as Aluffi “defines” it? Or is it those $\sigma$ themselves, so
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}_A}(f_1,f_2) = \left\{ \sigma \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(Z_1, Z_2) : f_1 = f_2 \circ \sigma \right\}?
$$
If this right, is it possible to have the actual diagram (whatever that really is, the definition in the book is somewhat unclear to me) as morphisms of some category, as Aluffi's language suggests?
Apologies if this is a somewhat silly question, but I would like to make sure that I don't have a wrong understanding of this (apparently important) example from the beginning!

It doesn't really make a difference: the actual elements of the hom set doesn't matter, and only the relations between them do. So as long as the composition is defined correctly you can view them as either single arrows or entire diagrams.

How do you mean? Doesn't it matter how they are defined in the sense that they have to fulfil the necessary axioms to be a category at all? Do you mean that it doesn't matter if you define them as the set in my question or as the diagrams? My problem is that I can't really work with the diagrams (beyond an intuitive approach), which probably means I don't really know what they are, exactly.

For fixed $f_1, f_2$, the set of commutative diagrams like the one you drew, however you define it, should be in bijection with the set you wrote down for $\mathrm{Hom}(f_1, f_2)$, so it doesn't matter. This is structuralism, as opposed to materialism. Your definition of the objects is wrong though: it should be $\sum$, not $\bigcup$.

@NaïmFavier I see, thank you. But why should it be $\sum$ and not $\cup$? How is the sum then defined?

$\bigcup$ indicates that you're working in material set theory, where $\mathrm{Hom}$ sets need not be disjoint. $\sum$ is a sigma-type in the sense of dependent type theory, which is a natural home for formalising category theory. You can interpret these as sets of pairs of an object $Z$ of $\mathsf{C}$ and a morphism from $Z$ to $A$.

@NaïmFavier So $\operatorname{Obj}(\mathsf{C}A) = { (Z, f) : Z \in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathsf{C}), f \in \operatorname{Hom}{\mathsf{C}_A} (Z,A)}$?

Yes, for example.

@NaïmFavier I see, this is perhaps why I was having problems trying to show the disjointness of Hom sets in $\mathsf C_A$ with my wrong interpretation of the definition. Thank you very much for your help.

@NaïmFavier This should potentially be another question entirely, but I am struggling to show the disjointness axiom; do I have enough information now, or am I potentially still running into the issue described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98028/verify-this-is-a-category/98358#98358

Oh, I just realised that Aluffi does ask for $\mathrm{Hom}$ sets to be disjoint... that is a very strange convention to take, and it does not hold for the usual encoding of functions as relations unlike he claims (the sets $\emptyset \to A$ and $\emptyset \to B$ are never disjoint). Anyway, this is an unimportant technical detail: if you want them to be disjoint, encode a morphism $f : \mathrm{Hom}(A, B)$ as the triple $(A, B, f)$.

@NaïmFavier Why not an official answer?

Concerning the disjointness of $Hom$-sets see my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4399501/349785.

@PaulFrost Thanks, that has cleared up the definition in the book, but I am still struggling with the actual proof, even with encoding $f\in Hom (A,B)$ as the triple $(A,f,B)$ (or in this case $(Z,f)$). Assuming two hom-sets in $C_A$ are not disjoint I get as far as showing that the $Z_1 = Z_3$ and $Z_2 = Z_4$, but the fact that $f_1 = f_2\sigma$ and $f_3 = f_4 \sigma$ doesn't get me anywhere in showing $f_1 = f_3$ and $f_2 = f_4$... am I missing something obvious?

The trick I mentioned works in any category. In this case, you would encode $\sigma$ as $(f_1, f_2, \sigma)$ and then the disjointness of $\mathrm{Hom}$-sets is trivial.

@NaïmFavier now I see, I was only looking at $\sigma$ as a morphism in $\mathsf C$, how silly. Thank you (again)!

Paraphrasing Trebor's and my comments: any correct definition of the set of commutative diagrams such as the one you drew will end up being in bijection with the set you wrote for $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}_A}(f_1, f_2)$, and category theorists like to think up to isomorphism (see structuralism, principle of equivalence), so, yes, that is the correct definition.
